# How to make an EC2 instance listening to two ports and displaying two different HTML pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following this free official tutorial from Amazone : AWS Cloud Practitioner Essentials (Second Edition)
https://aws.amazon.com/training/course-descriptions/cloud-practitioner-essentials/?nc1=h_ls

In the 4 course about Load Balancers(AWS Cloud Practitioner Essentials - Integrates services)

He created two EC2 Instances - He said he will show two containers listening to two different ports
on the brower he pasted the @IP of the first EC2 instance, he got a Html page
then he kept the same @IP and added port 443, then he got another html page butnthe URL stayed the same.

Any idea how he did that ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the first view was Non-SSl port number 80. Port number 80 is the default port to view any webpage.

As you have mentioned that second view was with Port number 443 which is default port for SSL web view.

We can configure two different web pages for different ports for the same IP

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, Port number 80 is for HTTP and port number 443 is for HTTPS. Based on the question, I presume he used the same public IP address of the instance for these two protocols.